# Redmine: rake db:migrate segfaults

Tags: rake, redmine

```
    [~/redmine]# RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  InsertBuiltinRoles: migrating =============================================
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-08 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-linux]

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Trying to install redmine and get this when trying to migrate database. Nothing on google, any advice? Have tried to use the mysql2 adapter, still getting a new segfault on every run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am tempted to say that the problem doesn't come from Redmine but from your Ruby installation.

Did you reinstalled / updated libyaml on your system ?

Side note: you should use Ruby 1.9 unless you really need 1.8 version.